# How can I add a currency field in list with currency string coming from data?

Tags: sonata-admin

(It is quite simple to add `currency` field in the list view

```php
protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
    {
        $showMapper
            ->add('price', 'currency', [
                'currency' => 'EUR',
                'locale' => 'fr',
            ])
        ;
    }
```

But what if my currency string (EUR, USD, ...) comes from the data itself (aka not like in the snippet but from a field from the DB table) ?

can I inject the `currency` string somehow ?

Comment: See this:https://sonata-project.org/bundles/intl/master/doc/reference/number.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a custom template for your item and then access to your object into it.

```php
    protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
    {
        $showMapper
            ->add('price', 'currency', [
                'currency' => 'EUR',
                'locale' => 'fr',
                'template' =>  '@AdminTemplates/sonata/show_currency.html.twig',
            ])
        ;
    }
```

```html
{# @AdminTemplates/sonata/show_currency.html.twig #}
{% extends '@SonataAdmin/CRUD/base_show_field.html.twig' %}

{%- block field -%}
    {% spaceless %}
        {%- if value is null -%}
            &nbsp;
        {%- else -%}
        {{ value|localizedcurrency(object.currencyField) }}
        {%- endif -%}
    {% endspaceless %}
{%- endblock field -%}
```

In this example, I use the `localizedcurrency` from the [Twig Intl Extension](https://twig-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intl.html)

If you are using the [SonataIntlBundle](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/intl/2-x/doc/index.html), your template can extends [show_currency.html.twig](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataIntlBundle/blob/2.x/src/Resources/views/CRUD/show_currency.html.twig), and maybe you would be able to override the `currency` field option.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

@Picoss solution works with Symfony 6.1 and Sonata Admin 4.18 using this `show_currency.html.twig` template:

```
{% extends '@SonataAdmin/CRUD/base_list_field.html.twig' %}

{%- block field -%}
        {%- if value is null -%}
            &nbsp;
        {%- else -%}
            {{ value|format_currency(field_description.option('currency')) }}
        {%- endif -%}
{%- endblock field -%}
```